# Why doesn't my TabbedPrintWriter work?

Tags: java, printwriter, auto-indent

I am writing a java decompiler. To give the output a nice indent, I have decided to write a class called `TabbedPrintWriter` to automatically tabify the output appropriately. Here's the code:

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class TabbedPrintWriter extends PrintWriter {
    private static int indentAmount = 4;
    private int indent = 0;
    public TabbedPrintWriter(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    public TabbedPrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush) {
        super(out, autoFlush);
    }

    @Override
    public void println() {
        super.println();
        for (int i = 0; i <= indentAmount * indent; i++) {
            super.write(' ');
        }
    }

    public void indent() {
        indent++;
    }

    public void unindent() {
        indent--;
    }

}
```

I also wrote a test class to test this:

```
public class TabbedPrintWriterTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TabbedPrintWriter writer = new TabbedPrintWriter(System.out, true);
        writer.println("Hello");
        writer.indent();
        writer.println("Goodbye");
    }

}
```

If you look at the code, each indent level should be four spaces. However, if I run this, I get this output:

```
Hello
 Goodbye
```

Yes, that's right. Only one space.

Why is this?

Comment: You're not overriding enough of the critical methods. Have you checked out the API? The source code? Also shouldn't the super method be called *after* the spaces are written out?

And what is your plan of action if print is called several times, and then a println? Are you planning to tab before very call to the `print(...)` method?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels delete that. Your answer already went through. I'm reading it.

Comment: I deleted my answer since it smells more like a comment.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Let me refresh.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have looked at the source code for `PrintWriter` and found that the only code that outputs a newline is in the `println()` method. The `println()` method calls a private method `newline`, but that method is not called anywhere else.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels My plan of action is to print indentation for a new line after the new line has begun. I don't really care about extra indentation at the end of the output.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So, I hope that is more clear.

Comment: Your problem has a flaw. Again, if prints are used, and then println, if your code's goal is to only indent the println, you'll end up with your tab in the middle of a String.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I thought of a new approach. I'll append output to the writer to a string buffer, then output the whole string buffer including indent when it is time to print a new line.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels After a significant rewrite, the code now works. Voting to close. (Yes, the OP can vote to close his own questions.)

Comment: This problem has been fixed and there is no need to further worry about it.

Comment: And you're going to tell us about your fix, right?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a rewrite of code and some debugging, I finally managed to get this to work:

```
public class TabbedPrintWriter extends PrintWriter {

    private static int indentAmount = 4;
    private int indent = 0;
    private StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

    public TabbedPrintWriter(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    public TabbedPrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush) {
        super(out, autoFlush);
    }

    @Override
    public void println() {
        for (int i = 0; i < indentAmount * indent; i++)
            line.insert(0, ' ');
        super.write(line.toString(), 0, line.length());
        line = new StringBuilder();
        super.println();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int c) {
        line.append((char) c);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(String s, int off, int len) {
        line.append(s, off, len);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(char[] buf, int off, int len) {
        line.append(buf, off, len);
    }

    public void indent() {
        indent++;
    }

    public void unindent() {
        indent--;
    }
}
```

Basically, I do line buffering and insert indentation prior to printing out the line. Now that it is working, I will not be needing the help of the community, so the primary reason is to make sure nobody gets distracted trying to answer a question that doesn't need answering. And to spread the word of a working tabbed print writer.